# How to add reward bounty to question of different user?

Tags: support

Just don't look at my score, because it will make you think that I am experienced SO user. Truth is, I am just passionate ;)

I totally like the [question about costs of Mars colony](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/4825/cost-of-colony-on-mars-moon-per-metric-ton) and I do not have time or passion to actually find answers for it.

While I already up voted it and Favorited it, I would like to draw even more attention to it by providing some of my internet points to someone answering it.

The question is obvious: How to do that?

Comment: It's only 4 hours old as of now. Give it some more time. In 2 days (I think) you will be able to set a bounty.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Please refer to the [Set Bounties](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) privilege help page. It also outlines which questions are eligible for bounties. (The question you linked to does not, at present, meet the criteria.)

In short, you should see a **start a bounty** action link below the comments (immediately below "add a comment" to the question). Click on that and follow the instructions. The screenshot in the help article appears to be slightly outdated, but should be close enough.

Remember that bounties are non-refundable.

---

> While I already up voted it and Favorited it, I would like to draw even more attention to it by providing some of my internet points to someone answering it.

*Favoriting* a question does not have any impact for other users. Basically, it's a way for you yourself to find your way back to a specific question a little more easily.

Comment: To expand - once the question has been on the site for a few days then it will become eligible for bounty, and at that point an option will appear to add one.